# Operator '-' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, topdown

```
target = transform.GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z));
crosshairs.transform.position = new Vector2(target.x, target.y);

Vector2 difference = target - player.transform.position;
float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message is quite clear.

There are [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) (automatic) conversions [`Vector3` -> `Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector3.html) and wise versa [`Vector2` -> `Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_Vector2.html) - meaning you can basically use both types exchangeable.

The operator `-` however is only defined for either [`Vector3 - Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_subtract.html) or [`Vector2 - Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_subtract.html).

So the compiler simply doesn't understand which one you want to use.

Knowing that `Transform.position` is a `Vector3` I can guess that `target` is a `Vector2`.

And since you want to have your result as a `Vector2` anyway simply convert explicitly

```
 Vector2 difference = target - (Vector2) player.transform.position;
```

---

Sidenote: Just fyi since vectors in Unity are structs you don't need to use `new` everytime.

Instead of e.g.

```
crosshairs.transform.position = new Vector2(target.x, target.y);
```

you can simply do

```
crosshairs.transform.position = target;
```

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay good catch, thanks! A bit sloppy from me ;)